# Web framework for a Legacy application: Grails or Play or?

Tags: spring, grails, playframework

Presently I work on a legacy application which has a Flex UI and ORM hibernate, SQL Server database. This application is heavily dependent on xml and database. It does have serious performance issues while fetching the data and rendering it on flex UI.
Two frameworks topped the search are `Grails` and `Play`. There are plenty of discussions on their differences and which one is better. But I could not find any comparison in the recent times. 
 Which one looks good in 2014?

Is there any other framework which can be considered? Like Spring MVC.

> > Note: This may not be a coding problem but I would really like to have opinion of people who code.